# Is there any function converting a list of tuple to dict with keys as the second element in tuple

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

As the title, I have a list of tuples like this:

```
words = [('word1', '+'), ('word2', '+'), ('word3', '-'), ...]
```

I want to convert it to a `dict` with the second element in each tuple as the key, and its value is a list of words. I know I can loop over it and add to a `defaultdict`, but is there any faster way or a builtin function with only one line of code in doing that?

Excepted output:

```
my_dict = {'+': ['word1', 'word2', ...], '-': ['word3', ...]}
```

I have tried this:

```
my_dict = defaultdict(list)
for word, key in words:
    my_dict[key].append(word)
```

Comment: That's three lines of very readable code that does exactly what you want. I would call that a win.

Comment: Yes, I hope there is an optimal way that faster than mine

Comment: I found a solution after googling, I'm not sure that faster than yours but you can try:

`from collections import defaultdict` 
`from operator import itemgetter `
`from itertools import groupby `

`test_list = [(1, 'gfg'), (1, 'is'), (2, 'best'), (3, 'for'), (4, 'CS')]`
`res = dict((k, [v[1] for v in itr]) for k, itr in groupby(test_list, itemgetter(0)))`

Answer (score 2):

you can use [more_itertools.map_reduce](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.map_reduce)  with `operator.itemgetter`:

> **more_itertools.map_reduce(iterable, keyfunc, valuefunc=None,
>   reducefunc=None)**
>
> Return a dictionary that maps the items in
>   iterable to categories defined by keyfunc, transforms them with
>   valuefunc, and then summarizes them by category with reducefunc.

```
from more_itertools import map_reduce
from operator import itemgetter


words = [('word1', '+'), ('word2', '+'), ('word3', '-'), ('word2', '+')]

map_reduce(words, itemgetter(1), itemgetter(0))
# defaultdict(None, {'+': ['word1', 'word2', 'word2'], '-': ['word3']})
```

---

also, you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

my_dict = {k : [t[0] for t in g] for k, g in groupby(words, key=lambda t: t[1])}
```

if your tuples are not sorted base on your second item from your tuples you have to sort your `words`:

```
from itertools import groupby

my_dict = {k : [t[0] for t in g] for k, g in groupby(sorted(words, key=lambda t: t[1]), key=lambda t: t[1])}
my_dict
```

this solution is **not** faster but you can write in one line